# Mock external dependencies in golang

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a program in go that connects to AWS S3 and gets a file.
I'd like to write some tests for it, but I'd like to know, more generally, how to do these mocks in Golang. I know there are some libraries to create mocks but if I remember correctly I read someone suggesting using only standard libraries for unit tests was the best way to go.

So, how would you test a function like this?

```
func (s S3Input) Sample(key string) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf []byte
    waBuf := aws.NewWriteAtBuffer(buf)

    _, err := s.Downloader.Download(
        waBuf,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(s.Bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(key),
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return buf, nil
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If I look at your code I don't know what logic you want to test there. 
The general solution in Go would be to take an interface as input. Then you would pass the dependency in your code and the mock in your test to that function.

Comment: This function offers nothing to "test", so why bother.

Comment: You're right this code doesn't have much to test. Mine was probably a more generic question like: "what are the best practices when unit testing with Go?" In ruby you could use doubles, does go need something similar or there's a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do it is to inject the dependencies in your structure, like such:

```
type S3Inputer interface {
    NewWriteAtBuffer(buf []byte) *aws.WriteAtBuffer
    String(v string) *string
}

type S3Input struct {
    newWriteAtBufferFunc func(buf []byte) *aws.WriteAtBuffer
    stringFunc           func(v string) *string
}

func (s *S3Input) NewWriteAtBuffer(buf []byte) *WriteAtBuffer {
    return s.newWriteAtBufferFunc(buf)
}

func (s *S3Input) String(v string) *string {
    return s.stringFunc(v)
}

func (s S3Input) Sample(key string) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf []byte
    waBuf := s.NewWriteAtBuffer(buf)

    _, err := s.Downloader.Download(
        waBuf,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: s.String(s.Bucket),
            Key:    s.String(key),
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return buf, nil
}

func main() {
    s := &S3Input{
        StringFunc:           aws.String,
        NewWriteAtBufferFunc: aws.NewWriteAtBuffer,
    }

    // ...
}
```

This allows you to replace those functions with whatever you want for testing, without the need of any testing framework.

Then, the testing function would look something like this:

```
func (s S3Input) TestSample(t *testing.T) {
    s3Mock := &S3Input{
        StringFunc:           (func (v string) *string {
            return nil
        }),
        NewWriteAtBufferFunc: (func (buf []byte) *aws.WriteAtBuffer {
            return nil
        }),
    }

    res, err := s3Mock.Sample(...) //
    // asserts & error checks
}
```

You could improve it by creating a `S3InputMock` type instead of reusing the base one, both would implement the `S3Inputer` interface and your mock could have attributes allowing it to help you with testing. For example, it could count the number of times a function is called, store the arguments it received, have its methods behave differently depending on the attributes you set for easier testing, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this could be one way to test it, even though as other people have said this specific snippet doesn't really require any real test as there's pretty much no logic.

Comment: Yes, but this approach isn't specific to your code, it's a general way to be able to test something that depends on external dependencies :) Let me know if I can help more!